# how to use filter() technique to generate integers from string?

Tags: python, filter

I am trying to use the filter() out numbers in a string:

```
s = "The Great Depression lasted from 1929 to 1939."

numbers = filter(lambda n: n==isinstance(s,int),s)

for i in numbers:
    print(i)
```

however, when I print `numbers` nothing is printed- any ideas why this is? Is my lambda function correct?

Comment: All of the characters you iterate over are instances of `str`, not `int`.

Comment: What's the expected output?

Comment: You have several fundamental misunderstandings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want it to print, you need to add list() to created a printable object. Otherwise, filter is only creating an abject, but it won't print.

```
s = "The Great Depression lasted from 1929 to 1939."

numbers = list(filter(lambda n: n.isdigit(),s))
print(numbers)
```

Or try this:

```
s = "The Great Depression lasted from 1929 to 1939."

numbers = list(filter(lambda n: n.isdigit(),s))

for i in numbers:
    print(int(i), end='')
```